# mod_rewrite two variables one index

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a rule like this and works:

```
http://domain.com/rewrite points to index.php?page=rewrite

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

now I need to add one more rule:

```
index.php?run=rewrite&task=more-stuff
```

and points to

```
http://domain.com/rewrite/more-stuff
```

any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Do you really mean you want `http://domain.com/rewrite/more-stuff` to rewrite to `index.php?run=rewrite&task=more-stuff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([\w-]+)$ ./index.php?run=$1&task=$2 [QSA,L]
```